# How do I Indent this Frame without starting all over again

Tags: modeling

Im Modeling a small TV that's just the size of the default cube. On the backside of it, I want to have ports for cables. I beveled the frame already.
I want it to go smoothly in this so that it is indent u shape I don't know how. If you have any ideas, help would be appreciated.

Blender File is attached.

[image]

[image: as you can see, the bend should happen where the red line goes and be shaped like in the little drawing.]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). You want to indent an area in that shape?

Comment: yes. I do how do I?

Comment: hello plese share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I uploaded the file now (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with n-gons, so it should be easy :).

1. Remove the back face entirely
2. Add a few vertices in it's place, and bevel to get a nice curve
3. Connect to the frame and fill
4. Inset the larger part a bit, and move front or back

*Back face removed, a few vertices added and beveled*
[image]

*Connect to the frame and fill*
[image]

*Inset the larger face a bit, and move front or back*
[image]

[image]

Comment: I sadly don't really know how to do that /:

Comment: Hi :). I'll be happy to provide some guidance, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: well, I just want to know how I can make this curve out of my frame. Besides, the topology I have is very different. I now also attached a .blend file and tried to explain better what I need help at.

Comment: Hi :). I checked the model, and updated the answer. It's fairly simple and detailed now.

Comment: Solved! Thank you some much for your time!

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project :)